# How to parse a JSON object ? (From server-side to client-side...javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json

I have a jquery interacting with a server side Web Method. The Web method accepts a string 'memID' from the jquery and executes SQL queries based on it. Then I create a class:-

```
public class Member
{
    // Objects of Member. //
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string HPCode { get; set; }
    public string OPfromDate { get; set; }
    public string OPthruDate { get; set; }


    public Member(string ID, List<string> hpCode, List<string> opfromDate, List<string> opthruDate)
    {
        id = ID;
        for (int j = 0; j < hpCode.Count; j++){ HPCode = HPCode + (hpCode)[j] + '*' };
        for (int j = 0; j < opfromDate.Count; j++){OPfromDate = OPfromDate + (opfromDate)[j] + '*' };
        for (int j = 0; j < opthruDate.Count; j++){OPthruDate = OPthruDate+ (opthruDate)[j] + '*' };   
    }
}
```

This class is used to return the results of my SQL query to the client side:-

```
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(member);
```

I used breakpoints and checked on the client side, indeed it is getting the return values. However I am not sure about what is the best way to parse these values and store them in variables on my javascript side so i can use them for client-side functionalities.

```
// Ajax function that sends member ID from client side to server side without a post back. 
function ajax() 
{
    $.ajax 
    ({
        url: 'Default.aspx/MyMethod',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify({ memID: mem_ID }),
        success: onSuccess, 
        fail : onFail

   });
}



// If client-to-server communication is successful. 
function onSuccess(data) 
 {
     confirm(data.d);
     var returnedstring = (data.d);
     var jsondata = $.parseJSON(data.d);

 }
```

Now how do I parse the 'data' ?? is there an eval function? or parse function?

Does anybody have any web examples? before this I was only passing back 1 value to my client side, so it was easy to get, now i am confused with multiple values.

**UPDATE:-**

I tried doing this on my javascript side:-

```
var returnedstring = (data.d);
var member = data.d.id;
var Hp = data.d.HPCode;
```

however when I use breakpoints and hover over them with my mouse, i get member and HP as undefined, however the returnedstring has all the correct values.. ... any idea?

**SOLUTION (I couldn't figure out the other way suggested in the answers, but this works for me) :-**

```
function onSuccess(data) 
 {
     // stores entire return in one string.
     var returnedstring = (data.d);

     // parses json returned data
     var jsondata = $.parseJSON(data.d);

     var member = jsondata.id;
     var HpCode = jsondata.HPCode;

}
```

Comment: Use Chrome / Firefox and run `console.log(data)` inside the success callback function.

Comment: console.log(data) doesnt work with either, no error messages, also with chrome and firefox - the update message that i was getting with IE with the confirm(data.d) command, that message is also not showing.

Comment: *console.log(data) doesn't work* .... did you open the JavaScript console to see what was output there?

Comment: yes, and this is all it had:-

[MAIN]  Connecting http://localhost:59160/Default.aspx slider.js:392
[MAIN]  requesting to load modules slider.js:392
[MAIN]  requesting to load modules

Answer (score 3):

Because you're using `dataType: "json"`, `data` is already parsed out of the JSON string. That's why you're able to access `data.d` in Javascript.

To access the members, you can do something like this:

```
console.log(data.d.HPCode);
```

Comment: Probably also worth mentioning that the code is not sending over the method parameter properly.

Comment: cool. As you can see I m very new to this technique. So how can I get 4 variables on my javascript side..


such that var memID = returned value of memID
var HPCode = returned value of HPcode

Comment: @Philosophia there's no need to call `JSON.stringify()` - jQuery will understand if you just give it the plain object. (The way it is now, the stringified object will look like an invalid query string.)

Comment: @Pointy: jQuery will use its typical URL-style encoding if you send the object directly. .NET MVC will bind correctly for simple values like the one used here, but if the data becomes very complex (like properties with arrays), it can cause problems. `JSON.stringify()` will allow it to send even very complex objects in a way that the model binder will understand.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Do you mean to say that on my javascript side, if I do something like this:-

var HPCode = console.log(data.d.HPCode);

it will work?

Comment: @Philosophia: No, more like `var HPCode = data.d.HPCode`. The code I provided would log the result to the browser console, which may be useful as you try understanding how the data came across.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior ah OK then. (weird.)

Comment: @StriplingWarrior when i do console.log.. it gives me a runtime error - console is not defined.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Also, now that my var HPCode is set to data.d.HPCode, i put a breakpoint on that line and check its value..and it says 'undefined' for its value when i hover over it with my mouse. Even though data.d has all the correct values when i hover over it.

Comment: @Philosophia: If you put the breakpoint on that line, then the line hasn't run yet. Try stepping to the next line before checking the value.

Comment: haha, true, i put breakpoints after the line too. so i had more variables and their corresponding values... still 'undefined'
var member = data.d.id;
                         var HPCode = data.d.HPCode;


                         // stores entire return in one string.
                         var returnedstring = (data.d);


                         var jsondata = $.parseJSON(data.d);

                         //console.log(data.d.HPCode);
                         confirm(data.d);

Comment: @Philosophia: I just noticed that you're actually returning the json-serialized object as a string from the server. Why not just `return member;`?